# What increases pet damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've seen the following claims:

- Attack speed does not increase pet damage
- 1% attack speed increases pet damage with 1%
- Crit does not affect pet damage
- Pet damage is mostly crit damage (may only apply on the big dog from Tall man's finger)

There's the obvious direct effect's that state pets in their text, so obviously they work with pets.

But can someone give clarity about exactly what stats on the hero increase pet damage?

As for the types of pets: is their damage not all calculated the same? If not it would be good to know the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look on Reddit many people have tried this and from my own experience playing a WD i can concur with the following information.

Al tho from one patch to another they change how pets behave interact with sets and set bonuses, this is a pretty accurate indication as to what stats actually affect your pets beside the legendary affixes and set bonuses/buffs

Stats which do give a DPS increase:

1. Attack speed (does not make pets attack faster, but simply makes them hit harder with their set attack speed)
2. Critical hit chance (same critical hit chance as your sheet dps)
3. Physical skill deal more damage % (for a phys based pet)
4. Main stat (Intelligence in this example as I tried it out on a witch doctor)
5. critical hit damage (has a static 50% crit dmg and can't get boosted by stats)
6. splash damage (does not proc any of the splash despite trying for over 30 min)

Answer (score -1):

What kind of pet? If we're talking witch doctors:

Fetishes benefit from the same DPS increases you do -- INT, crit damage, crit chance, attack speed*, +damage, elite damage and Pierce the Veil. +Physical% affects all fetishes (as well as physical dogs). Fetish Sycophant fetishes do not benefit from +Fetish Army damage.

*IAS -- not T&T's secondary affix -- doesn't make pet attack faster, but DOES make them hit harder.

Comment: Why downvote? Is he wrong?

Comment: @MrFox without any backup its just claim, Id like to see a source or some in game proof of that